# How to control how empty strings are updated and serialized

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Here's a JSFiddle to demostrate my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffreyrswenson/YMFec/7/

I have a viewmodel that has one or more observables.  I create most of them like:

```
var x = ko.observable();
```

When I tab though the input elements, the values are changed from undefined to "".  Because I serialize the VM as part of some "Dirtyflag" logic, the value being changed is causing some problems.

I tried:

```
var x = ko.observable("");
```

This causes knockout-validation to not work as I'd like.

I can use this.toJSON() or a JSON replacer to make sure that the JSON is serialized the way I'd like it to be serialized. (I prefere this.toJSON(), but can use either or both)

So is there a better way to do this?  Like is there a way to tell Knockout to leave a value as undefined if an input is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Like is there a way to tell Knockout to leave a value as undefined if
>   an input is empty?

You could use a binding handler to do that. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/YMFec/8/)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.undefinedVal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
            if (value.length === 0) {
                $(element).text(typeof "undefined");
            } else {
                $(element).text(value);
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Unfortunately, this causes the validation to stop working.  I think it's a good idea.  I'm trying to sort it out now...

Comment: @Jeff see this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/YMFec/9/)  - It's using a custom validation rule. Only thing is, after you tab through the `lastName` input field, the `lastName` observable get's assigned a value of `""`

Comment: @rwish45, you last change fixed the issues I commented on.  Ultimately I didn't use your answer, but it was good information and helped me come to what I finally used.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom extender that will convert blank strings to undefined.  This allows for the Validation and JSON to work as I need / expect.

Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates the custom extender: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffreyrswenson/Gwse8/2/

```
ko.extenders.undefinedIfBlank = function (target, option) {
    if (option) {
        var convertBlank = function (newValue) {
            if (typeof newValue === "string" && newValue.length == 0) {
                return undefined;
            } else {
                return newValue;
            }
        };

        var result = ko.computed({
            read: target,
            write: function (newValue) {
                var current = target();
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    var convertedVal = convertBlank(newValue);
                    if (convertedVal === undefined) {
                        target.notifySubscribers(newValue);
                    }
                    target(convertedVal);
                }
            }
        }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

        var tempVal = convertBlank(target());
        target(tempVal);
        result(target());

        return result;
    }

    return target;
};
```

Even though I didn't use @rwisch445's answer I have accepted that answer.  It is a viable answer and I think for some people it will be the one they'd prefer to use.